# Find and update an array of Swift enums with associated values

Tags: swift, enums

I am trying to find a better way to handle the situation described below. Let say that I have the following types that describe elements on the screen:

```swift
struct PickerState: Equatable {
    let date: Date
    let color: Int
}

enum ScreenItem: Equatable {
    case pickerStartDate(state: PickerState)
    case pickerEndDate(state: PickerState)
    case button(title: String)
}

struct  ViewState: Equatable {
    let items: [ScreenItem]
}
```

and then the view state that holds values of these types `let viewState: ViewState = ViewState(items: [])`

Let say now I need to update the `.pickerStartDate` with a new date and keep the color. The one way to do it I can think about is as it follows:

```swift
func updateStartDate(with date: Date) -> ViewState {
    let startDateIndex = viewState.items.firstIndex {
        if case .pickerStartDate(state: _) = $0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    let item = viewState.items[startDateIndex!] // force unrap for demo purposes
    if case .pickerStartDate(state: let state) = item {
        let newState = PickerState(date: date, color: state.color)
        var items = viewState.items
        items[startDateIndex!] = .pickerStartDate(state: newState)
        return ViewState(items: items)
    }
    return ViewState(items: viewState.items)
}
```

It's quite a bit of a code to write and if `ScreenItem` will hold more different types (e.g `.toggle(state: ToggleState)` + pretty much anything with it's own state) is there a generic way to have one update function for all of them?

Comment: Can you describe in words (in addition to the code that you provided) what you're trying to do? Are you trying to update the first item that is a `ScreenItem.pickerStartDate` with a new date, keeping the color? What do you mean by "if ScreenItem will hold more different types"?, do you mean if has more associated values? What's the complication that you're trying to avoid

Comment: Updated. One thing to mention is that `.pickerStartDate` might not be the first one or if some items (think about them as cells in table view) can be removed so the order in the `viewState.items` might be different.

Comment: You design looks incorrect to me and I don't understand the use of an enum here. For instance isn't pickerStartDate and pickerEndDate a pair that belongs together? What will the `items` array really contain, one of each from the enum or?